# Putting media into an Access Database using Java

Tags: java, sql, database, eclipse, ms-access

I'm making an email system in Java using an Access database as connectivity. What would be the best way to get and upload media/files (.gif, .au, .mpeg and .txt) attachments to the access database? What datatype would the field in the database have to have? I think that i have to convert the file to binaries to be able to store them, i have no idea how i would retrieve them so i can open them in the Java GUI. Could any body explain how to do this so i can add it into my program, or explain any alternatives?

Comment: I don't no how to go about it, so  i was wondering what way to do it, i thought there may only be one way.

Comment: An Access db file is subject to a hard-wired limit of 2GB.  Will that be enough to hold all your media files?

Comment: Just adding to HansUp's comment. I know this doesn't answer your question but I think SQL Server or MySQL would be a much better choice. In fact, you might consider storing the attachments/files in the file system and just saving relative paths and file names in your database. SQL Server has a feature like this built in called FileStream (starting with Version 2008 I believe).

Comment: It has to be access unfortunately, 2GB is perfectly fine too!

Comment: I think, what i need to do it convert the file(image) to a byte array for it to be stored in the database?

Answer (score 1):

OLE OBJECT is really the only option you have if you want the actual binaries to be stored in an Access Database.

You'll probably be able to use `setBlob` and `getBlob` to work with it.